# eMMC chip change. Does not work for unknown reason

Tags: pinout, replacement, emmc

Because of the chip crisis, I had to use (the only ones which were available at the time) different eMMC chip.

Originally it was MTFC16GAPALBH-IT, but I have temporarily replaced it with MTFC4GLWDM-4M AAT.

Pinouts are slightly different but the most important pins are the same.

[image]

Those less important are marked as not internally connected (RFU)

[image]

But unfortunately, new chips do not work.
Maybe you have some experience with similar eMMC chip swaps?

EDIT.
Does not work means that I cant establish communication with the chip. That communication does work with the larger size chip (this device was manufactured already). The logic analyzer is not conclusive as chip is not going out from the power-up power state (reading the OCR register). If I receive the correct reply is not clear at the moment - at least the MMC/SDIO uC peripheral is not complaining.  At the moment I am connecting the old device to LA and will compare the traces (not a very easy task as both uC & eMMC are BGA :))

Comment: @Finbarr added some explanation. BTW the spell checker has added some nonsense words.

Comment: RFU is not the same as NC, I would even state that the table comment is a lie, RFU **may have** internal connection, in the fine print  it states RFU must be left floating and not tied to ground, this usually is indicative of potential for nascent function or test use,  it appears there is a change of some kind in the RFU, in your current IC they are now specified as VSF[1-8],  so there may be an internal conflict , how certain are you that this isn't the reason for the issue? Could you cut those traces and float those pins to confirm? Also counterfeit is not out of question.

Comment: https://octavosystems.com/app_notes/designing-for-flexibility-around-emmc/

Comment: @crasic - Official channel + all required documents.  100% genuine. Micron has confirmed that they are not connected.

Comment: Personally, I would confirm the fact for myself. Could be differences in protocol, default states, registers, IDs such that the software drivers give up or don't work, your logic analyzer test is a good approach.  PCBA mfg error, slight differences in balling or packaging they weren't prepared for, try more boards for more N,  and particularly suspect any rework for BGA  Another suggestion: closely review errata. You are doing everything right, confirming an alternate under the gun is hard, the lesson for me was to plan alternates into the design phase for exactly these situations. .

Comment: Ps if I had something more concrete to offer I would provide an answer, but I don't,  hopefully there is a smoking gun that someone sees. Good luck!